# R Shiny - Sequential text output

Tags: r, shiny

I want to print a text first, before processing the code and then print a confirmation after the code is executed.

Here is my code (ui and server of app.R):
All unspecified variables are initiated within the app.R file.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel(h1("Order2Ship", align="center")),
  # Sidebar iputs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( #LONG LIST OF INPUTS
    ),
    # On Screen output
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("START"),
      textOutput("Confirm")
    )
  )
)
# Underlining code for output (computes the whole each time an input is changed)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$Do, { # ignores all return values
    output$START <- renderText({"Starting Analysis"})
    O2S( #LONG LIST OF PARAMETERS, FROM INPUTS
    )
    output$Confirm <- renderText({"Analysis Done"})
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I do not need any returns from the function `O2S`, it basically takes one file as input and generates a solution file. But, both the text outputs are showing at the same time, after the function has run. I cannot figure it out. I just started out with Shiny, so sorry for such a naïve question.

Comment: That is because the `renderText` for both start and confirmed is passed from the server  to ui only after the function runs.

Comment: I understand, but how do I fix that?

Comment: maybe I am missing something but all I see when I run your app is *Order2Ship*. Nothing else...

Comment: What if you take your first `renderText` before the `observeEvent` function? Doing that will run your code in the following sequence: display `Starting Analysis` text in `mainPanel`; run the code to input file and generate solution file; display `Analysis Done` in the end.

Comment: @mlavoie the required data and some of the code is omitted to make this short. Create a O2S function, and a action button for do, you can replicate the behavior.

Comment: @Sagar that works. However, I want the message after the button is pressed. Anyways, thanks. I now added a "Select Parameters" message before `observeEvent`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use *shinyjs* to create a chainevent something like this

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel(h1("Order2Ship", align="center")),
  # Sidebar iputs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( #LONG LIST OF INPUTS
      actionButton(inputId = "Do",
                   label = "Start")
    ),
    # On Screen output
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("START"),
      textOutput("Confirm"),
      useShinyjs()
    )
  )
)
# Underlining code for output (computes the whole each time an input is changed)
server <- function(input, output) {
  startText <- eventReactive({input$Do},{
    runjs("Shiny.onInputChange('analysisStarted',Date.now())")
    "Starting Analysis"
  },
  ignoreInit = TRUE)
  output$START <- renderText({startText()})
  observeEvent(input$analysisStarted, { # ignores all return values
    temp <- NULL
    for(i in seq(50000)){
      temp <- c(temp,i)
    }
    runjs("Shiny.onInputChange('analysisFinished',true)")
  },
  ignoreInit = FALSE)
  confirmText <- eventReactive({input$analysisFinished},{
    "Analysis Done"
  },
  ignoreInit = FALSE)
  output$Confirm <- renderText({confirmText()})
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you please explain how it works? As far as I get it, `runjs` is creating some sort of flags, but why do we have `Date.now()` once and `true` the other time in `Shiny.onInputChange` function? Also, why `true` instead of `TRUE`? Is that because it is written in JavaScript?